# Best Way to Retrieve Over 500 Deleted Blog Posts from Caches?

Tags: blogger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering a lost website with no backup?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/recovering-a-lost-website-with-no-backup)

SITUATION:  My blog was recently hacked and over 500 posts were deleted. I have restored the security of the blog, but stupidly didn't have any backup so now I'm out 500 posts which were very, very important to me.  I had started retreiving them one at a time by searching each individual post, going to the cache source code, then putting that post id into Blogger's post editor.  It was slow going, but it was working perfectly, it imported everything - dates, times, labels, tags, etc.  No comments, but I have all those saved in email.

Unfortunately, this suddenly doesn't work anymore and I have barely recovered a quarter of the posts.  The cached results are still out there, but the pasting post id's into blogger's post editor isn't working anymore.

QUESTIONS:
Is there a way to pull ALL my cached results from google back into my blog?  It seems like there SHOULD be since blogger is a Google application, but so far I haven't found any way to do that.

If that's not possible, is there a way to get blogger to let me go back to doing what I was doing before?

Alternatively, is there another way to recover these posts (preferably with their previous dates and labels)?

I really appreciate any help!  I will be backing this sucker up monthly from here on out!

Comment: have you read http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/recovering-a-lost-website-with-no-backup already ? good luck!